# Input type hidden dosent hide in form when the value is larger in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to setup hidden input field value to  an xml string which is obtained from an array .
But the `hidden` field value is displayed in `html`  while when i put a normal text as value in the hidden field it works fine.

```
//a large sized associative array convert to xml and set as hidden field 
            $item_array=array();
            $xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<OriginDestinationOption/>');
            array_walk_recursive($item_array,array($xml,'addChild')); 
           echo '<input type="hidden" name="return-xml" value="'.$xml->asXML();.'" />'; ?>
```

But it displays the value in html form.Whats wrong with my code?

Note:I am using codeigniter framewrok

Comment: It is also possible that your values contains double quotes

Comment: Shouldn't `echo '<input type="hidden" name="return-xml" value="'.$xml->asXML();.'" />'; ?>` be `echo '<input type="hidden" name="return-xml" value="'.$xml->asXML().'" />' ?>` ? Remove the semi-colon at `asXML()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" name="return-xml" value="'.str_replace('"',"'",$xml->asXML());.'" />'; ?>
```

Comment: It is also possible that your values contains double quotes

Answer (score 0):

The data will be overflowing the input. Try to add css to input as "overflow:hidden"

Comment: check for the quotes inside your value of "$xml->asXML();".